# Application requires a device running 'N'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm trying to test my app against Android N using Eclipse.  I am getting the error, Application requires a device running 'N' when I try to debug it.

I have created an emulator for an android device running Android N.
[image]
Here's my console log:

```
[TTB] Android Launch!
[TTB] adb is running normally.
[TTB] Performing com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivityBasic activity launch
[TTB] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AndroidN'
[Emulator] Hax is enabled
[Emulator] Hax ram_size 0x80000000
[Emulator] HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
[Emulator] console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
[TTB] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[TTB] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[TTB] ERROR: Application requires a device running 'N'!
[TTB] Launch canceled!
```

Here's a snippet from my manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="N"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

Any thoughts on what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that Eclipse ADT has the possibility of upgrading to the N SDK. Anyway, try `android:minSdkVersion="19"` along with `android:targetSdkVersion="23"`

Comment: what if you set both min & target to `"N"`? You currently have the target lower than minimum.

Comment: I originally set min to 19 and got this error, Platform N is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'N'.  I'll try setting both to N.

Comment: `"N"` is not a valid API Level. It must be a **number**. Also, as I said, `I'm not sure that Eclipse ADT has the possibility of upgrading to the N SDK`

Comment: Setting both to N didn't work either.  Eclipse project properties allows me to set the Project Build Target to N.  Thanks Bob and zapl.

Comment: From what [I can find](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L74), `"N"` in the manifest xml is the correct value. Might be an eclipse issue (because it's no longer supported since forever now), if you go by http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html it starts with "Get Android Studio 2.1" :)

Comment: Maybe it's time to ditch Eclipse in favor of Android Studio, thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's time to stop following Google caprices and remain on the older, stable APIs... I'm very happy with Eclipse, `android:minSdkVersion="8"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="18"`.

Comment: And... `"N"` is for the `build.gradle`. Not for the `Manifest`, I guess. I don't know. I don't even use `Gradle`. And I'm so happy not to!